# Preventing HTML reflow

Tags: javascript, html, css, reflow

I'm working on a webpage with user-resizable columns, and I'm having trouble with reflow when a column is resized, which causes elements to be pushed down and out of alignment as the column narrows. However, Google docs doesn't appear to have this problem; you can resize the documents list and it will cut off text rather than push it down to the next line. Looking at the CSS, I can't figure out which CSS property is responsible, so if anyone has any ideas, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: please post the HTMl and CSS. A live example or fiddle will be much helpful. The propetry used is overflow

Answer (score 1):

Try this CSS to hide anything outside of the bounds of your container:

```
overflow: hidden;
```

More info:  http://www.htmldog.com/reference/cssproperties/overflow/